be able to be his go to
Please advise the meaning of "be able to be his go to" of the paragraph below:

Iwamasa, using code words like "Dr. Pepper," indicated Perry wanted more ketamine in the following days, according to prosecutors, and Chavez and Plasencia were determined to get it for him. "I think it would be best served not having him look elsewhere and be able to be his go to," Plasencia allegedly texted Chavez.

It is quoted from page 30 of People magazine Sept. 2, 2024 issue. –

It looks like this text is quoted from somewhere: can you add a reference for where you found it? Is it from a court transcript, a novel, etc.?

Also, the expression "go to" is defined here: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/go-to (look under noun)

It is quoted from page 30 of People magazine Sept. 2, 2024 issue.

In Collins Dictionary's definition for go-to as an attributive adjective, it says

You use go-to to say that someone or something is the best person, place or thing for a particular purpose or situation.

go-to
This meaning can also be used in the noun definition:

singular noun
Go-to is also a noun.
Google has become mostly everyone's go-to for answers.

Here Plasencia allegedly told Chavez that they should aim to become the best persons,  Perry's choice, Perry would approach for his needs.
(The context didn't clarify whether Plasencia wanted Chavez or both of them to be the go-to, and I interpret it as both of them.)
